# mySQL Left Join with multiple tables

Tags: mysql, oracle, left-join

I've got 3 tables linked together using foreign keys. One of the tables contains data that may be null, but I still want it displayed. I've also got multiple conditions worked in.

This is what I have so far, but it doesn't work:

```
SELECT ord.OrdNo, ord.OrdDate, cu.CustNo, cu.CustFirstName, cu.CustLastName, em.EmpNo, em.EmpFirstName, em.EmpLastName
FROM OrderTbl ord, Customer cu, Employee em
WHERE cu.CustNo=ord.CustNo
AND em.EmpNo=ord.EmpNo (+)
AND ( OrdDate BETWEEN '01-Jan-04'
AND '31-Jan-04')
AND cu.CustState = 'CO'
```

Basically, the employee info might be null on the order table, but I still want the entries displayed. Any help would be appreciated, since I've only started learning SQL.

Edit: There were no errors in running this above query. It's just that I was missing results that had null fields.

Comment: if you are getting errors while executing query then please mention the error here.

Comment: If you are using Oracle, correct the tags.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Pleaes use `JOINS`, to be precise in your case LEFT JOIN to show all Employees' orders:

```
SELECT ord.OrdNo, ord.OrdDate, cu.CustNo, cu.CustFirstName, cu.CustLastName, 
em.EmpNo, em.EmpFirstName, em.EmpLastName
FROM OrderTbl ord
  LEFT JOIN 
  Customer cu
    ON  cu.CustNo=ord.CustNo
    AND cu.CustState = 'CO'
  LEFT JOIN 
  Employee em
    ON  em.EmpNo=ord.EmpNo
WHERE OrdDate BETWEEN '2004-01-01' 
                  AND '2004-01-31'
;
```

Reference:

[Visual Representation of JOINs:](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/33052/Visual-Representation-of-SQL-Joins)

[image]

Comment: @Cyrallia glat you got it worked `:D` going forward please take a look at how `JOIN`s can make your queries efficient and clean.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT ord.OrdNo, ord.OrdDate, cu.CustNo, cu.CustFirstName, cu.CustLastName, em.EmpNo, em.EmpFirstName, em.EmpLastName FROM OrderTbl ord, Customer cu, Employee em WHERE cu.CustNo=ord.CustNo AND em.EmpNo=ord.EmpNo AND ( ord.OrdDate BETWEEN 'YYYY-mm-dd' AND 'YYYY-mm-dd') AND cu.CustState = 'CO'
```

YYYY-mm-dd this supported in between clause. ex:-
from date= 2013-01-01
to date=2013-01-31

try like this. may it will help you.